# CSS - Fixing bug with TABLE

Tags: html, css

Original Tabe:
[image: Original table]

My Table:
[image: My Table]

On your first look there is a difference, it become in 2 ways first is color of fonts which is not really important atm. What is important is that my ICON is far away from rest of the text and its not in the middle of the line, can somebody help me to fix it?

My CSS:

```
tr {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
td {
    padding: 7px 30px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color:999999;
}
.icon {
    background-image: url("images/cs_icon.png");
    background-size: 24px 22px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
td a{
    color:#1a6eb6;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

My HTML:

```
              <table>
                <tr>
                <td class="icon"></td>
                <td>Public server#1</td>
                <td>IP: 88.88.88.87:270115</td>
                <td>Mapa: de_dust2</td>
                <td>Hráči: 40/60</td>
                <td><a href="#">Detail</a></td>
                </tr>
.....
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Fzw7L/

Comment: "make layout by photos", provide a fiddle, please...

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be because you specified your icon to have `padding-right: 20px;`!

Try removing that, or lessening the value to something like 5px to reflect your mockup

Comment: I found out why, its because you specified EACH TD to have `padding: 7px 30px`. All I needed to do was create a special class for your server table row and override the padding on the left to be much less.



Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fzw7L/2/)